# Angular unintentionally redirects to localhost:4200/#

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

When attempting to `this.router.navigate(['newcard']);` it correctly loads the URL but then immediately redirects to localhost:4200/#.

Here is how I'm redirecting from showcard to newcard.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreateNew()">
  <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
</a>
```

```
onCreateNew(){
  this.router.navigate(['newcard']);
}
```

newcard is the default generated by running `ng generate component newcard`

Here is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NewcardComponent } from './newcard/newcard.component';
import { ShowcardsComponent } from './showcards/showcards.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'newcard', component:NewcardComponent},
  {path: '', component:ShowcardsComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { NewcardComponent } from './newcard/newcard.component';
import { ShowcardsComponent } from './showcards/showcards.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewcardComponent,
    ShowcardsComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try  this.router.navigate(['/newcard']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the first problem that comes to my mind is your `<a>` tag which is meant to navigate to `localhost:4200/newcard`.

You are using `href="#"` and `(click)="onCreateNew()"` which are 2 different routes and probably create the error, since the `href` gets called first and after that the route doesn't match anymore because it would open `localhost:4200/#/newcard` or just fails otherwise.

### Solution

Remove the unused `href` property in your `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreateNew()">
  <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
</a>
```

I also recommend you to use `[routerLink]` directly in your template. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="newcard">
  <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Hope this helps, reach out if you have more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `href="#"` from the `<a>` element. Believe this results another redirection when the link is clicked.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreateNew()">
  <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `[routerLink]` attribute without the `click` event.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['newcard']">
  <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
</a>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6ekxka?file=src%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: this worked thank you!